# Олимпиадная задача на графы

Tags: c++, графы, олимпиада

Постановка задачи следующая:

Город состоит из n площадей, между которыми проходят n − 1 улиц. Известно, что по любой улице можно перемещаться в любом направлении, а так же что от каждой площади можно добраться
по улицам до любой другой. Периодически патрулирующие город экзорцисты обнаруживают потустороннее существо на какой-то площади, после чего высылается отряд для поимки существа.
Если существо со скоростью d было обнаружено на площади v, оно может скрыться от экзорцистов, если есть путь от площади v до площади на расстоянии строго больше d от нее. Чтобы не
упустить демона, перед тем, как высылать отряд, экзорцисты перекрывают некоторые улицы. Ваша
задача — помочь экзорцистам оптимизировать этот процесс. Поскольку в городе праздник, хочется
перекрывать как можно меньше улиц!
Для каждого из m событий вида «обнаружен демон со скоростью d_i на площади v_i» определите, какое минимальное количество улиц надо перекрыть, чтобы с площади v_i были недостижимы
площади на расстоянии, большем чем d_i, от нее.

Вся проблема в ограничениях: 1 <= n, m <= 10^5; 1 <= v_i <= n; 0 <= d <= n;

Идеи следующие: для поиска расстояния между вершинами в дереве можно использовать LCA (https://e-maxx.ru/algo/lca), который можно предподсчитать за O(N) и потом искать за O(log N) или предпосчитать за O(N log N) и искать за О(1). Однако получается, что нам все равно надо от данной площади посмотреть все достижимые, и это можно сделать только за O(N), а для одного запроса это слишком долго. Как это оптимизировать?

Comment: Какой длины улицы между площадями?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можно считать, что 1

Comment: Если требуется отрезать какое-то ребро, то сразу можно отрезать его предка ближайшего к `v`. Задача сведена к "какие улицы выходящие из `v` нужно перекрыть, чтобы глубина оставшегося дерева была не больше `d`".

Comment: Для этого на каждом ребре надо написать два числа (в двух направлениях). Числа такие: "если ребро удалить, то дерево растущее из его правого конца будет иметь такую-то глубину". Второе число для левого конца.

Comment: Числа строятся рекурсивно от листьев за линейное время. Задача решена!

Comment: Дайте адрес проверяющей системы, пожалуйста.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за ответ, адрес: https://pcms.itmo.ru/pcms2client/party/contests.xhtml

Comment: Войти туда я не могу. :(

Comment: Да, извините, тестирующая система уже закрыта и сдать ничего нельзя(